# Running two wildfly instances of different versions simultaneously with intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

I am using two version of wildfly 14 and 11 to test the same application in intellij ultimate 2018. when i run or debug application i should change the JBOSS_HOME manually in the environment variable of windows.

```
JBOSS_HOME: "C:\Development\servers\intellij\wildfly-11.0.0.Final"
JBOSS_HOME: "C:\Development\servers\intellij\wildfly-14.0.1.Final"
```

I have already added `-Djboss.home.dir=C:\Development\servers\intellij\wildfly-14.0.1.Final` to the vm option of run/debug configuration but no effect.

**Is there a way to set it up in the intellije run/debug configuration?**

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Do you need any other assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure 2 different app servers in IntelliJ IDEA and 2 run/debug configurations, where you would specify these 2 application servers. Then just start both configurations for each app server instance.